# Different size for my application between my phone and an emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, size

*Sorry for my english I am french.*
**Hello, I have a problem with the size of my application when it installed.**
The apk: 7,1Mo
On the emulator the size installed is 24Mo.
On my phone the size installed is 68Mo.
I use Android Studio.
Please help me I do not understand anything. I am looking for an answer for several hours but nothing.

Comment: Maybe this can help you to know what's happening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609595/app-install-size-the-same-on-different-device-types :)

Comment: Thank you but it did not work for me. I do not understand why such a gap.